# Bash Recursive search

Tags: bash

I have started to make a script that will recursively search through the files in a folder. What I need to do is compare them with the modified times in another folder. I currently have a string like `compare1/folder/file.ext` but I now need to tell it to do `compare2/folder/file.ext`. How would I change the base folder so I can compare the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Still not 100% sure what you're looking for, but if you want to replace a string in a variable, you can do:

```
FILE=compare1/folder/file.ext
OTHER_FILE=${FILE//compare1/compare2}   # replace compare1 with compare2

echo $OTHER_FILE    # will print compare2/folder/file.ext
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be what I need.

Comment: You should accept this answer to show the question is solved, and to give thanks for the answer. +1 for deciphering first.

Comment: I would give thanks but I need 15 rep so marking it as the answer will have to do.

Comment: I upvoted one of your other questions, you now have enough reputation to upvote any answer you have found helpful on the site.